# How do I use l3docstrip?

Tags: latex3, documentation, documentclass-writing, docstrip

I've got a [bundle](https://github.com/vermiculus/yacv) I'd like to properly document (and begin to release) that uses `expl3` intimately, and it should be documented similarly to `expl3` itself (as seen in `texdoc interface3`.

I did a little research and tried to get the real-live uses on SVN to work, but they seem to depend on the fact that `l3docstrip` is a sibling file in that directory.
How should I write `myclass.dtx` and `myclass.ins` to conform to convention?

Is there an example similar to David Carslisle's [model DTX file](http://www.texdev.net/2009/10/06/a-model-dtx-file)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `l3docstrip` package is an extension of the standard DocStrip bundle, and adds on one very specific feature: replacing `@@` by a module prefix. For the 'user' (in this case the package author), the use of `l3docstrip` is intended to mirror closely that for DocStrip. Thus in place of

```
\input docstrip.tex
```

in the demonstration DTX file, all that should be needed to use `l3docstrip` is

```
\input l3docstrip.tex
```

Assuming that you have an up-to-date installation, `l3docstrip.tex` will be present as part of the `l3kernel` distribution.

That will load `l3docstrip`, but in order to get the 'magic' to happen you need to include the module prefix information. This will read

```
%<@@=module-prefix-here>
```

and can in principle appear anywhere after loading `l3docstrip` and before the first code line to be extracted. By convention, this should appear in the source just before the code, for example

```
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*package>
%    \end{macrocode}
%    
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<@@=prefix-goes-here>
%    \end{macrocode}
%
% Version data to start with.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\ProvidesExplPackage
```

Perhaps the best guide to this 'in the wild' in the source for [`notes2bib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/notes2bib): this is a relatively small package using `expl3` syntax and maintained by a member of the LaTeX3 team.

Comment: Is there any way at all to use multiple prefixes? Anything like `<@@@=@@_submodule>`?  I don't expect that `l3docstrip` supports this by default, but do you think that it can be extended in a night or two's work?  Ideally I'd like to have functionality where  I can define multiple shorthands so I can keep a `\<class>_<package>_<description>` but still be able to change the name if, heaven forbid, it's taken before I can release.  (Do you think this is rather a job for `sed`?)

Comment: @SeanAllred In principle yes but I'd steer well away from it. I don't see how you are structuring things: if your module subdivides, the parts should be well-defined.

Comment: I'm trying to design a sort of layering system (*approximating* the idea of LaTeX3) for a resume/CV document class.  It's detailed in the readme (first link in Q), but basically I define `yacv_[module]_[logic|presentation.[style]].sty`, where all functions/etc. share the structure of the file.

Comment: `yacv.cls` then takes key–val setup arguments (indirectly via a document command) to load those modules' logic and styles.  (Definitely off–topic for the Q—the readme goes into more detail.)

Comment: @SeanAllred To be honest, `expl3` classes are not really something we should have encouraged at all! The LaTeX3 model is that functionality should be in packages, with classes about design. At the moment we don't have the design layer sorted, so there are some compromises, but basically use `expl3` for your package code and 'traditional' approaches to design.

Comment: Then what about the layer beneath design?  Looking at your [published witchcraft](http://latex-project.org/papers/2013-10-24-latex3.pdf), I would say `yacv` and `*.logic.sty` belong more to the functionality layer than design (which are in `*.presentation.*.sty`).  Is this not what was intended?

Comment: (In witchcraft terms, I've both the documentclass definition layer and documentclass realization layer both using `expl3`.  Is there a different language that will be used for this?  …actually that rather sounds like another question entirely.  At any rate, thanks for your help with `l3docstrip` :-)